# Spring boot + angular ошибка 403

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot

Я делаю проложение с JWT аутентификацией с использованием Spring Security. Когда я делаю запрос с использованием postman, все работает. Но когда я делаю запрос с использованием angular приложения, я получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код angular компонента, из которого я делаю запросы:

```
onSubmit() {
   const formData: FormData = new FormData()
   formData.append('playlistId', '1')
   formData.append('name', 'ads')
   formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name)
   formData.append('genre', 'fds')

   const headers = new HttpHeaders()
   headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data;');
   headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.tokenStorage.getToken())

   this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/song', formData, { headers: headers }).subscribe(data => console.log(data), err => console.log(err))
}
```

Я храню jwt токен в localstorage. tokenStorage - сервис, который при вызове метода getToken() берет токен из localstorage.

Код spring boot контроллера, на который должны приходить запросы:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/song")
public class SongController {

    private final SongService songService;

    public SongController (SongService songService) {
        this.songService = songService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public HashMap<String, String> createSong (
            @RequestParam("playlistId") Long playlistId,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam("genre") String genre
    ) {
        var songDto = new SongDto(playlistId, name, file, genre);
        songService.createSong(songDto);

        HashMap<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("ok", String.valueOf(HttpStatus.OK));

        return response;
    }
}
```

Мой файл конфигурации:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                //.antMatchers("/api/song/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(UserRole.ADMIN.getRole())
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.apply(new JwtTokenFilterConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean () throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Если я разкоментирую строку `//.antMatchers("/api/song/**").permitAll()` запрос выполняется без ошибок.

Есть идеи как пофиксить ошибку?

UPD: я сделал println в своем jwt фильтре авторизации, и выяснил, что токен не приходит в фильтр. Это проблема неправильного отправления запроса? Если да то в чем проблема?

Comment: Видимо как-то не так из ангуляра хапрос делете. Покажите как вы его из PostMan делаете и сравнивайте все части запросов пока не найдёте где отличие.

Comment: Нужно смотреть на отличия в заголовках? Тела запросов идентичны

Comment: Если тела идентичные, то да, надо на другие части смотреть

Comment: Веб часть крутиться на другом порту? Включите cors и используйте аннотацию CrossOrigin как вариант.